# numpy - meshgrid for multiple dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

numpy has a beautiful function which generate multidimensional grid. It is easy to work with it when number of dimension is low and is known in advance, but what to do when number of dimension is only known at time of execution or simply big and it takes too long to type. I guess I am looking for something like

```
 import numpy as np

 x = np.meshgrid(y)
```

where y is an array of arrays of evaluation points, for example

```
y = [array([-3.,  0.,  3.]) array([-3.,  0.,  3.]) array([-3.,  0.,  3.])]
```

Suggestions?

Comment: It works! What is this magical operator *y? Cannot find anything in Google.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Thank you again! You should post it as the answer along with the link, if you have time.

Comment: Warren - could you put this in an answer so it can be checked off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `*`-operator (i.e. the unpacking operator):

```
x = np.meshgrid(*y)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists